# Does using the preSign function in 0x v4 require gas?

Tags: 0x

I am reading about on-chain orders in the docs for 0x v4 here:

https://docs.0x.org/nft-support/docs/introduction#on-chain-listings

Is using the preSign function when generating an order on 0x v4 an on-chain transaction that requires gas?

Answer (score 0):

Yep, you will still need to submit the preSign in a transaction which requires gas

Answer (score 0):

`preSign` functionality is definitely very convenient when listing NFTs on Polygon.

I'm actually building an Open Source project to help developers list NFTs securely using a simple REST API - this could be very helpful to what you are building. I've started creating the documentation [here](https://app.gitbook.com/o/wqOt4RHETlFohMQdoeGb/s/ixXEnIHShN4SAt8COpuL/) and you are welcome to reach out in my DMs if you would like to test the product!